# Hidden Object game in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android and so planning to start with Hidden Object game. I had few question to ask  will it be feasible to make hidden object with android or I should use Cocos2d ( in a way both will be new experience for me ). As I was working with what will be the logic and how will I make that game.

If I use only android libraries for the Hidden Object game then how will I do that one scene n number of layer ( logic what I thought is One scene i.e. Image and n object will be place in n layer )
now how will I work with n layers at a time is it possible in the android ? or anything that sort of ?

How will I go about object found or object touched part ( I was thinking that keeping one transpartent color rectangle on the object image and the touched will find the rectangle position ? ( I may be wrong sorry just sharing what i thought)

All suggestions are appreciated....

Comment: One question per question post usually works much better on this site. Try breaking up and refactoring your question so that you can ask a small, well-defined and answerable question.

Comment: ok i will seperate it ...thanks ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would recommend is to start with a reading a book about Android Game Development. If you just start developing a game, without proper knowledge about game development, you'll end up with a game that will run slowly, will look bad on some devices, and maybe will not be playable at all.

Here is a good book for [Beginning Android Games](http://www.apress.com/9781430230427).

I am not aware of any books for `Cocos2D for Android` and there are very few tutorial so I would recommend using `Android` without `Cocos2D`, since for your type of game, it would be not such a complex task (but still, reading/learning the basics of game development will help you A LOT).